# Даны три числа А,В,С. Если все числа положительные вычислить Z = А+В+С, если все отрицательные - Z = (А+В)*С, в противном случае Z=A*B*C

Tags: java

как нужно записать этот пример 
помогите пожалуйста (JAVA)

Comment: Ну а вы уже попробовали сами решить? Можете показать код?

Comment: Псевдокод. Если а>0 И б>0 И ц>0, то з=а+б+ц, иначе если то же, только <0, то з=(а+б)*ц, иначе последний вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a = ...; // Вместо трёх точек значение
int b = ...;
int c = ...;
int z;

if(a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
    z = a + b + c;
else if (a < 0 && b < 0 && c < 0)
    z = ( -1 ) * ( a + b ) * c;
else
    z = a * b * c;
```

Comment: Если отвечать на такие вопросы, ТС со следующей своей домашкой опять к нам пойдет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat из-за этого ты и минусушь, несмторю на правильность решения?

Comment: @michael_best Да. И не я один, похоже.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat гениально. Поставлю тогда +

Comment: @michael_best: то есть Вы поддерживаете появление вопросов рода «Сделайте за меня» на ruSO?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я поддерживаю и уважаю работу автора этого поста. А мой голос никак не мешает закрыть вопрос

Comment: @michael_best: Вы называете «работой» репофармерство на вопросе, который был задан, чтобы ТС сам не делал свою домашку? У нас это не поощряется. У нас база знаний, а не биржа фриланса

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я что, вопрос плюсую?! я плюсую ответ, если он был правильный, мне понравился, или что еще угодно. к вопросу это не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @michael_best: к вопросу это имеет прямое отношение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91505/discussion-between-michael-best-and-kir-antipov).

Comment: @michael_best: если автор ответа видит, что он достигает своей цели на подобных вопросах (пофармить репутации), то он продолжит отвечать на подобные вопросы. А пока на эти вопросы отвечают, они будут продолжать появляться. Мы боремся за чистый ruSO